# What could the motivation be for god-like beings to create sentient life?

Tags: worldbuilding-process, gods

In the process of creating the backstory of my world, I came to a major roadblock.  That roadblock is: why would the gods of my setting create a world for multiple species of sentient life?

Context: The seven gods, or Great Ones as they are called later on, were all collectively different alien races that existed light years from each other and were never close enough to interact.  Then, a Lovecraftian abomination with the mind of a two year old comes along and starts munching on these races and many others.  Most races die out, but the races that the seven come from each have one survivor that, through one way or another, has become a being of great power.  But still weaker than the abomination that strolled past their section of reality.

After a centuries or two in shock and mourning, these seven beings, remnants of there respective species, encounter each other and after another few centuries of moping around and understanding each other.  The seven decide to stop the being the killed there loved ones, i.e their species and launch what is basically a guerrilla campaign against the eldritch being that after aeons of fighting, eventually weakened the being enough that killing it seemed possible.

The issue is that why, during this time, they go off and create a fantasy world?  Humans exist on this other world along with other races that have evolved on this world with the assistance of the seven.  And further more, the seven have brought it upon themselves to teach the races both science and what is basically the magic of this setting.

My question is why?

As for the gods themselves, they are may have eldritch power but are still ultimately social creatures that need social interactions to stay healthy (although their health at this point is questionable).

EDIT: The Gods are also ultimately benevolent.  Since the story is about the events of what happens after the child-like entite finds this world and gets pummelled by the gods while it also pummels the gods in return.

Comment: Some good answers here: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/6581/why-did-god-create-man

Comment: It is not possible for the creature (= us, the mortals) to comprehend the creator (= God, or a god in general). We cannot know God's plan; ours is to belive that God has a plan to submit willfully.

Comment: These being are not gods, they are just really, really powerful mortals.  Kinda.

Comment: How do you judge the "best" or "right" answer? Without that, the question is opinion-based and hence not really a good fit for the site.

Comment: @Cadence Strangely this seems obvious. The answer that provides the best motivation for the gods doing their stuff. Usually the OP will know it when they see it.

Comment: This may be a good time for one of the tests I propose for "is this a good question?"  Can you come up with an answer which *doesn't* answer this question?  Is there any reason for creating life which would not satisfy your question?  I'd start with everything that has ever motivated a human being, and ask if it's possible to reject it as an answer to this question.  A good questions should, at the very least, have some non answers.  As a trial set: love, hate, boredom, pride, greed, and uncertainty are all very reasonable roots for such motivation.

Comment: I read over the my question and I could’t see how it could be opinion based.  Could someone explain what I need to change?

Comment: @Seraphim It is opinion based because we have insufficient information to guide our answers. We don't know these gods' personalities, or what might be gained or lost through the creation of a species, or whether it would give them and edge in their fight or be a severe weakness and handicap, or whether they've simply gone mad, or whether there are other factors that I haven't guessed. Basically, the real answer is "What do you want it to be?" and that isn't a question this site is able to answer.

Comment: @MrSpudtastic Thank you for your clarification.  Looking at the answers I got before the on hold took place.  I think I have found what I was looking for.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One reason could be that they simply want to rebuild and to defeat the acts of the abomination. If this eldritch abomination came and killed so many of their kin, then creating a new world would be a way of restoring their loss and representing that their hated foe failed to conquer them.

No better revenge than a life lived well. Except maybe creating new life.

Comment: This...this beautiful.

Comment: This has to be the answer.  The immortals go there and hang out and remember.

Answer (score 4):

There are many stories, in which a higher being creates a world into the chaos around it. Some times, it has a sort of philosophical cause. Sometimes the supreme being has a fine and detailed plan, in that his creation fits into.

- **We are merely an ant farm**
  As you stated, these Great Ones are socialy active beings and you describe them with somewhat humanlike emotions. So it might be reasonable that they would like something to watch, something curious to spectate or of those Great Ones are like gods in this fantasy world, they could think of us like their pets. Less personal like dogs or cats, but like an ant farm to care for.
- **A Case Study**
  As you stated, the lovecraftian abomination is a childlike entity, not really thinking much about what it does. Your Greater Entities might want to study and learn from the creatures in the world they created. For them, these creatures behavior might look like the childlike abominations behavior, so they can study it, just to hope and find any weaknesses of the monster they are fighting.
- **True Power**
  In some stories, higher entities had created other races and creatures as their tools. in 40k, the Eldar were created by the Old Ones as a weapon against their enemies. Compared to the Eldar, the Old Ones were gods, but were fighting their godlike counterparts. The Old Ones created the Eldar with the power to manipulate the warp, the weakness of their opponents.
  It might be possible that your Great Ones created the world as a weapon, a breeding ground for soldiers or maybe just as a research center to find other ways to defeat their opposition. That may be the cause, why the Great Ones gave your fantasy races magic: to learn, experiment and refine it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer, of course, is in your question itself. The seven "gods themselves, they are may have eldritch power but are still ultimately social creatures that need social interactions to stay healthy".

Perhaps, the sentient races they create may not have the same social charge of health givingness that god to god interactions provide, but that would only provide an incentative to create lots of them.

Also, this health rejuvenating sociability with sentient races would help to build their strength to finally squelch that eldritch abomination with the mind of a two year old.

Comment: The same reason humans tell stories, play RPGs etc. They are social creatures and need a social and creative outlet, and maybe a distraction from the harrowing situation they face. Centuries of harrying Cthulhu or his buddy must get kind of wearing...

Answer (score 1):

Something you might want to consider is the origin of these Gods themselves. If you have intelligent being created by other intelligent beings, and you need a reason for that creation, you could tie in yet another creation, where even higher intellects created these God-like aliens. When an intelligent race reach a certain level in their evolution, they gain the knowledge to create a race beneath themselves. This could go up for infinity, where every race was created by a higher intellect, while humanity in this story is the lowest, or close to the lowest, rung on the ladder.

But this is just a suggestion - I can't do the worldbuilding for you!